# Maximizing function over a line

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Let

$$J(x,y) := x - h(y)$$

where $h : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $h''(x) > 0$ for each $x$. For $p, q > 0$ and $c \in \Bbb R$ the problem is:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & J(x,y)\\ \text{subject to} & p x + q y = c\end{array}$$

1. What is the value of Lagrange multiplier?
2. Find the solution $(x,y)$ as function of $p$ and $q$?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $L(x,y,\lambda)= J(x,y)-\lambda (px+qy-c)$, take partial derivatives, solve for $\lambda$, etc.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What's with the reference to Tarski?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Oh, he wasn't always Tarski? Never knew.

Comment: after we define the L(x,y,λ) how the solution is represent? :\